# How to create a custom URL in apache Superset?

Tags: routes, apache-superset

I am working on a project where I have am using conditional binding in my navbar i.e. when I am logged in as a testUser I will see the navbar left vetically and if I am an admin I will see the navbar top horizontally. Now I want to create a custom dashboard when clicked on "Dashboard" (I have attached the image for reference). I am integrating a different theme for the users but whenever I click on Dashboard I am routing to dashboard/List/ but i want to redirect to a custom url so that the user sees the theme that I have applied for them.

P.S. The admin panel will see the inbuilt dashboard only (means no changes for the admin)

I have tried modifying the routes.tsx in side pages/views but that is not helping.